# Laravel 5.0, Multi Language Website

Tags: laravel, routes, multilingual

Following is what I have done to achieve multi lingual feature for static text.

Step 1: Open up config/app.php and add the following below 'locale' => 'xx'.

```
'locales' => ['en' => 'English', 'sv' => 'Swedish'],
```

Step 2: Prefix your routes

To prefix our routes, we change the map method in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php. Change the map method to the following:

```
public function map(Router $router, Request $request)
{
    $locale = $request->segment(1);
    $this->app->setLocale($locale);

    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'prefix' => $locale], function($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

Then add this to the top of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Step 3: Create a language middleware

Now create a file named Language.php in app/Http/Middleware with this content:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

class Language implements Middleware {

    public function __construct(Application $app, Redirector $redirector, Request $request) {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->redirector = $redirector;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Make sure current locale exists.
        $locale = $request->segment(1);

        if ( ! array_key_exists($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.locales'))) {
            $segments = $request->segments();
            $segments[0] = $this->app->config->get('app.fallback_locale');

            return $this->redirector->to(implode('/', $segments));
        }

        $this->app->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Now make that middleware run on all requests by adding it to the $middleware property in app/Http/Kernel.php. It is recommended to add it to the top of the array.

```
protected $middleware = [
    'App\Http\Middleware\Language',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```

All the above has been taken from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website)

After doing all above, my routes do not pick the language automatically ... 
my root is

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'WelcomeController@about');
```

And if I give complete path in pages like
http://localhost:8000/pl/about

It works.

But I want that it should automatically pick the path means there should not be need of giving complete URLs in pages.

is it correct and how this can be achieved?

I know that in some way I need to work on routes.php but I don't know how to make it work.

I have very limited knowledge in Laravel as I am working on my first project in Laravel

Comment: Actually you should really just take the accept language header from the request itself. You can read more about it here https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4

Comment: I don't think I understand it ... what I should do? and where I should place this accept language header

Comment: Also on form submit I get following error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:`

Comment: I am using following as solution that in all posistions in entire website I am using link as ** {{ Request::root() }}/{{ App::getLocale() }}/page_name**   so in form action OR Redirect of a page OR to hyperlink an text or image I am using full URL as **{{ Request::root() }}/{{ App::getLocale() }}/page_name**  and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a good website shouldn't use different languages for different sites, instead it should occur based on the accepts language header. (Bearing in mind locale does not equal locations .e.g. a US site and a UK site might use different urls or domains even, as the site's offerings change between locations).

What you should do in the context of Laravel is implement a middleware which will read the accept languages header from a request and compare the languages wanted with what's offered by the site, in your case en and sv. This way the url doesn't determine the language, instead the settings of the user's browser does. If I'm using a browser in Swedish ideally the site should provide me the same language if available.

In the middleware can use the following code:

```
App::setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage(['en', 'sv']))
```

setting the language based on the request.

Then using the basic systems already available in [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization#language-files) you can simply put your translations into the correct files and then output the right locale strings based on the request. Negating the mess that is detecting the locale via routing or using different views for each locale.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have never used accept language so don't know where to define it and how to access it. Should I use  this code `App::setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage(['en', 'sv'])) ` in the Language Middleware that I have?